# Can I create a DBLINK on someones SCHEMA using oracle 11g express edition ... i have an access on the schema but i dont know how to connect on his DB

Tags: sql, oracle11g

1. I Installed Oracle 11g express edition to have my own database [local] we called it DB A , now i want link my DB to another DB [remote] we called DB B. is that possible?
2. I know the us/pw of the DB B but is it possible all the commands will be created to DB A ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as both your databases are defined in your tnsnames.ora, then you can create the dblink.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK <link_name> TO <schema> IDENTIFIED BY <pw> USING 'tns_entry';
```

Dblinks are what you use to connect schemas between databases.

To test it:

```
SELECT * FROM <table>@<link_name> where rownum=1;
```

Comment: hi sandman thanks for the script,I have successfully created a dblink but found a problem with my TNS,can u help me?

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
12154. 00000 -  "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

my script: 
CREATE DATABASE LINK "RS" CONNECT TO "RS_DB" IDENTIFIED BY "RS03"  
USING 'DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = RS_DB)))';
Below is my TNS
RS_DB = 
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=RS_DB)
))

Comment: CREATE DATABASE LINK RS CONNECT TO RS_DB IDENTIFIED BY RS03 USING 'RS_DB'

Comment: You have a schema called RS_DB in your database called RS_DB?  The "connect to" part must be a schema (user with objects like tables)

Comment: yes sandman with active tables ...is there a problem with my TNS 

RS_DB = (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=RS_DB) )) ?

Comment: btw i'am using oracle sql dev.. and when i'am adding a database i don't usually use TNS..I always use '+' sign and manually encode the DB details

Comment: instead of service_name you can try (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = RS_DB))

Comment: hi sandman , I Tested my TNS and it's properly working but 
still I encountered this error 'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified 12154. 00000 - "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified'.

Comment: when I used this script
SELECT * FROM <table>@<link_name> where rownum=1;

Comment: Just don't use service_name in your tns.  There could be many other reasons why you get 12154, and you will have to check metalink.  Cannot troubleshoot a 12154 over this forum.

Comment: ok ... thanks .. i will try it.. currently the remote server is down .. i will give u an update once done.. then ask another Question ;) ... thanks  my man sandman...